# set two elements width equal to container using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two div inside container and those divs should be settled according to the width of container and there should be a proper space between them

```
<div id="testimonial-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="inline-section row">
            <li class="signature-interior-features green-background col-sm-5 col-md-5">
                <div class="signature-interior-content">
                    <h2>Signature Interior Features</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Full-sized washer and dryer in every home</li>
                        <li>Walk-in closets and walk-in pantries and
                        vaulted ceilings available*</li>
                        <li>Appliance packages with multi-cycle dishwasher,
                        range and frost-free refrigerators</li>
                        <li>Large stainless steel sinks with disposal</li>
                        <li>Linen closets</li>
                        <li>Cozy wood-burning fireplace in every home</li>
                        <li>Spacious patios with exterior storage</li>
                        <li>Individual hot water heaters</li>
                        <li>Electric HeatM</li>
                        <li>Pre-wired for phone, cable and high-speed Internet access</li>
                        <li>Interior packages available*</li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!--signature-interior-content-closed-->
            </li>
            <li class="community-elements-details sky-background col-sm-5 col-md-5">
                <div class="community-elements-content">
                    <h2>Community Elements</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Clubhouse with social room and kitchen</li>
                        <li>Athletic center with cardio equipment and free weights</li>
                        <li>Sparkling outdoor swimming pool</li>
                        <li>Invigorating indoor spa</li>
                        <li>Complimentary tanning studio</li>
                        <li>Sports court</li>
                        <li>Close proximity to the Sounder commuter train and
                        the Super Mall</li>
                        <li>Only minutes to Emerald Downs and I-5 with
                        easy access to Highway 167 and Highway 18</li>
                        <li>Professional on-site maintenance</li>
                        <li>Professional on-site management
                        *in select apartment home</li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!--community-elements-content-closed-->
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--container-closed-->
</div><!--testimonial-wrapper-closed-->
```

Comment: Change `col-sm-5` & `col-md-5` to `col-sm-6` & `col-md-6`, respectively.

Comment: but they should have equal width as well

Comment: `col-sm-6` is the half of the container's width (which is 12 columns). That should set your columns' width as equal. But if you want empty space between the columns, I guess you can keep `col-sm-5` and just insert a blank `col-sm-2`' between them.

Comment: If you want the 2 column gap between; put a `col-sm-offset-2` & `col-md-offset-2` onto your 2nd `li`?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I saved my time..really appreciated !!